# Can the Docker driver on OpenStack coexist with libvirt.LibvirtDriver?

Tags: openstack, docker

The following documentation [link](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/config-reference/content//docker.html) indicates that the docker driver needs to be configured on **all compute nodes**

from

```
compute_driver= libvirt.LibvirtDriber
```

to

```
compute_driver=docker.DockerDriver
```

Does this means there will not be an option to select the instantiation of a normal VM ? Will the horizon UI allow to select which type of virtualization ( docker vs kvm ) to be selected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In openstack you cannot have hybrid compute drivers unless they are separated by AZs.  So it's either one or the other.

Of course the hackish work around would be to spin up an openstack compute instance inside of the docker / lxc environment and join it to a new az as a libvirt node....

a bit of inception there though, and it makes your scheduler basically worthless.

Answer (score 1):

With the basic OpenStack you can't, but you can write and add a filter which makes it possible... Just write a class with a host_passes method and add your new filter to nova scheduler filters.

I did it and it works.